# Not able to loop json object in angular2

Tags: javascript, json, loops, angular5

I have a respone object like below:
[image]

If I am looping through this object its giving me error
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**

My code:

```
 getBooklist() {
         return this.http.get('https://anytime-library-d705a.firebaseio.com/books.json')
      .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
    }

this.dataStoreService.getBooklist()
    .subscribe((booklist: Book[]) => {
        console.log(booklist);
        this.books = [];
        booklist.forEach(element => {
          const y = element;
          this.books.push(y as Book);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`booklist` it's an object, not an *array*.

You have to use `Object.keys` method.

```
Object.keys(booklist).forEach(key=> {
    this.books.push(booklist[key] as Book);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`booklist` is an Object it does not have built in iterator.

Change:

```
booklist.forEach(element => {
          const y = element;
          this.books.push(y as Book);
        });
```

To this using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method:

```
Object.values(booklist).forEach(element => {
          const y = element;
          this.books.push(y as Book);
        });
```